# A puzzling verse from Jacqueline Risset's La Divine Comédie

Tags: grammaire, poésie

I'm having a hard time parsing this bit of Dante (from Jacqueline Risset's translation of La Divine Comédie):

> C'était le temps où le matin commence,
>   et le soleil montait avec toutes ces étoiles
>   qui étaient avec lui lorsque l'amour divin
>   bougea la première fois ces choses belles;
>   si bien qu'à espérer me donnait lieu
>   de cette bête au gai pelage
>   l'heure du jour et la douce saison;...

What is the subject of `donnait`? (I would have expected to see `donnaient`, but that's not what my copy says.) What is the `de` in `de cette bête au gai pelage` doing? Maybe le soleil lui donnait lieu à espérer de cette bête au gai pelage l'heure du jour et la douce saison? But I don't understand how to read `l'heure du jour et la douce saison` as direct objects.

For comparison, here's the corresponding passage from the Lamennais translation, which I find much easier:

> C’était le temps où le matin commence, et le soleil montait avec ces étoiles qui l’entouraient, quand le divin Amour mut primitivement ces beaux astres ; de sorte que le gai pelage de cette bête fauve, l’heure du jour et la douce saison me conviaient à bien espérer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jacqueline Risset's translation is closer to the oldest known word ordering.

Here is an old version of these verses:

> *sì ch’a bene sperar m’era cagione
>
>   di quella fera a la gaetta pelle
>
>   l’ora del tempo, e la dolce stagione*

Its word-for-word French translation can be:

> *ainsi qu'a bien espérer m'était l'occasion
>
>   de cette bête sauvage au gai pelage
>
>   l'heure du temps, et la douce saison*

It can be understood that way:

> L'heure et la douce saison m'incitaient à l'optimisme face à cette bête sauvage au pelage gai.

---

> - What is the subject of *donnait*?

It can't be but *l'heure du jour et la douce saison*. My wild guess is Risset used the singular in ***donnait*** lieu because in the Tuscan text *m'**era** cagione* is also using the singular and not the plural which would have been *m'**erano** cagione*.

---

> - What is the *de* in de cette bête au gai pelage doing?

It is part of *bien espérer de cette bête* (to positively hope from this wild animal).